# Showing notifications on Motorola Active Display

Tags: android, notifications, lockscreen, motorola

I'm looking for the way how to show notification on the Motorola X style, or other devices with Active Display functionality.

I've read whole internet, twice. No result. 
Default notification is not showing on active display.
My base idea was to extend NotificationCompat with WearableExtender class. But notification is still only in tray/lockscreen, not on active display.

Current code:

```
    NotificationCompat.WearableExtender wearableExtender =
        new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender().setHintHideIcon(true);

    // Create notification
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .setSmallIcon(getSmallIconId(context, intent))
        .setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.primary))
        .setGroup(group)
        .setNumber(count)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(message)
        .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .extend(wearableExtender);

    // Show notification
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
        (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotifyMgr.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Does anyone know the trick?

Comment: I have the same problem, and found some comments that visibility should be set to public with `notificationBuilder.setVisibility()`. But that didn't help me neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes i really hate android. After 2 days i got a solution.

The solution is pretty simple, you have to call:

`.setGroupSummary(true)`

and notification finally appears.

Comment: Rememeber to resize the large icon bitmap to 128x128 (if you use setLargeIcon) otherwise the picture won't be displayed by Active Display.

Answer (score 0):

Your small icon must be bitmap, not vector graphic.

Comment: I got bitmap with size 72x72 for xxhdpi. The problem must be somewhere else.